# Guidelines for writing a framework

Tags: frameworks

I'm faced with writing a framework to simplify working with a large and complex object library ([ArcObjects](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/ArcObjects/ao_start.htm)). What guidelines would you suggest for creating a framework of this kind? Are static methods preferred? How do you handle things like logging? How do you future proof your framework code from changes that a vendor might introduce?

I think of all of the various wrappers and helpers I've seen for NHibernate, log4net, and code I've read from projects like NLog and [NetTopologySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/) and I see so many good approaches, but honestly I'm at a loss where to start.

BTW - I'm working in C# 3.5 but it's more about recommended approach rather than language.

Comment: +1. (If you can get ESRI to think about these issues themselves, +150!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brad Abrams' [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756) book is all about this. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write code to be more flexible.  For example, if you have a method that accepts an array as a parameter, would you be able to accept an IEnumerable or IList instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're consistent is more important than what conventions you go with.  As far as future-proofing yourself, that's a matter of the code that you're making a framework for.  It's a lot easier to build on a brick house than a sand one.

Answer (score 1):

Writing code for framework is absolutely very different from writing application code.

I have always consulted (and have others consult) the [Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke.aspx) when writing framework level code.